# practice questions - vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm working my way over some practice questions and have hit two that I have no idea on.

> 14. Find a vector parametric equation for the plane containing the points whose position
>   vectors are $u = (1, 1, 1)$, $v = (2,-4,-2)$ and $w = (10, 2, 7)$.
>
> 25. Determine the Cartesian form of the plane which passes through the point $(3, 2,-5)$
>   and which is orthogonal to the line $(x, y, z) = (3t - 1, 8t + 2,5t - 7)$ with $t \in\mathbb{R}$.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to record some prompting questions here:

1. A point and a vector uniquely determine a line. What determines a plane?
2. How many vectors span a plane?
3. Can you determine that many vectors on your plane?
4. What do equations for planes look like?
5. A plane is also determined by a point and its normal vector. What does it mean for a vector to be orthogonal to another vector?
6. What have you tried? I recommend trying things.